# Assigning categories based on certain conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

[image]

#Query

I want a formula to replicate the Ball_no. column

Temp shows the ball no's in an over of cricket game which goes till 6 because 6 balls are there in an over.

The condition is that if the delivery is an extra i.e. ***a wide/no-ball then ball no. will not change***. Hence, 1st delivery which is a wide is assigned as 0 balls bowled where as 2nd ball which is not an extra gets the 1st no. and 3rd ball is a no ball so in place of getting 2 is counted as 1.

How can we do that using an if statement? or any excel function. Any leads on it will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in E2, I would just increase the previous row by one unless it's a wide or no ball. However, I have had to use the n function to make it work for the first row:

```
=IFS(D2="wide",N(E1),D2="noball",N(E1),TRUE,N(E1)+1)
```

You could also use Countifs:

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D$2,"<>Wide",D2:D$2,"<>noball")
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The above only works for one over. If you wanted to continue for more overs, you could try

```
=IF(C2=1,(D2<>"wide")*(D2<>"noball"),G1+(D2<>"wide")*(D2<>"noball"))
```

in column G.

The countifs would be

```
=COUNTIFS(D2:D$2,"<>Wide",D2:D$2,"<>noball")-COUNTIF(C2:C$2,1)*6+6
```

(subtracting 6 each time a new over starts)

[image]

Comment: how can we modify the code to restart the counts if del count changes to 1 after 11, as per the above formula it goes on increasing

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to lookup the Delivery count for each temp no? If so place this formula next to each temp no:

`=XLOOKUP(temp No value,  column reference of the ball count, column refernce of the Delivery no)`

And if you need help generating the Ball no use this formula and drag down (the $ is very important here)

`=COUNTIFS(ExtraTypeColumnLetter $1: ExtraTypeColumnLetter 2, "NA")`

Comment: no I want a formula to replicate the ball no. based on extra type. Here, the delivery count indicates the actual number of balls bowled by a bowler in the game of cricket. If the ball turns out to be wide/ no ball then the bowler receives a penalty of delivering the same ball again. Hence, 3rd delivery which is a no ball gets ball count as 1, 1st delivery which is a wide is considered as 0 balls bowled. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: How to modify the formula to restart the count if the del count becomes 1 again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Index Match with Multiple Criteria.